# Symfony and Doctrine - The identifier id is missing for a query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developping a website for a small business and I'm facing an unknown problem ...

In the admin panel, I can manage my menus, contents etc... 
For menus management, I succeeded

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($menu)
        ->add('nom', 'text', array(
            "attr" => array(
                'placeholder' => "Nom du menu",
                'class'       => 'input-small'
            )
        ))
        ->add('ordre', 'integer', array(
            "attr"  => array(
                'placeholder'   => "Ordre",
                "class"         => 'input-small'
            )
        ))
        ->add('parent', 'choice', array(
            'placeholder'   => '-',
            'choices'   => $parents,
            'required'  => false
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label'=>'Ajouter',
            'attr'  => array(
                'class' => 'btn'
            )
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

I handle it correctly and it works. But now, I try it with another content to manage :

```
$blocInfoNew = new AccueilModif();
    $formNewInfo = $this->createFormBuilder($blocInfoNew)
        ->add('titreBloc', 'text')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            "label"     => "Save"
        ))
        ->getForm();
[...]
return $this->render("[...]:page_accueil.html.twig", array(
        'page'              => "Administration - Modifier la page d'accueil",
        [...]
        'formNewInfo'         => $formNewInfo->createView()
));
```

With a simple HTML form to test :

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="blocAddInfo">
    {{ form_start(formNewInfo) }}
        <p class="f_legend">Ajouter une info</p>
        {{ form_widget(formNewInfo.titreBloc) }}
        {{ form_widget(formNewInfo.save) }}
    {{ form_end(formNewInfo) }}
</div>
```

All works fine, until I send the form to the controller...

> The identifier id is missing for a query of [...]\AdminBundle\Entity\AccueilModif
>   500 Internal Server Error - ORMException

I searched all the internet without finding a solution >< Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Can you post your  AccueilModif.orm.xml or AccueilModif.orm.yml  file ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this happens when you misuse the find function.

```
->find($id)
```

It always has to contain a valid id, if you give it null it will throw the exception The identifier id is missing for a query...

I don't see it in your provided code but it looks like it is in:

```
$formNewInfo->createView()
```